# Change first setup ubuntu logo image

Tags: iso, customization, plymouth, logo

I embarked on the idea of creating my own Ubuntu image with the addition of some AI features. As it turned out, one of the most challenging task was to change the Ubuntu logo at the first OS boot. When updating the ISO image in `/usr/share/plymouth`, the following were replaced:

- ubuntu-logo.png,
- bgrt-fallback.png,
- and others.

The files in `/usr/share/icons` & `/usr/share/pixmaps` have also been replaced.

The following were registered in the chroot: `update-initramfs -u`, (*in GRUB, "quiet splash" is also specified.*). After selecting "try or install", etc. (grub-menu), the system starts to load, but the logo remains the standard [Ubuntu one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGv0z.jpg). However, if you continue with the installation or complete it, the desired logos are loaded.

Hence the question:
how to make the logo changes apply from the very first launch of the ISO?